# Using Material design Fragment is not passing to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using material design navigation drawer from this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

,and from first fragment i am trying to redirect to another fragment,but my application got crash,and showing errors,

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0053 (info.androidhive.materialdesign:id/container_body) for fragment All_Products{41ca7008 #0 id=0x7f0d0053}
```

ShopFragment.java

```
rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   All_Products tf = new All_Products();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("catagory_name", "All");
                    tf.setArguments(bundle);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.container_body, tf);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });
```

activity_main

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: if your going from one fragment to another should you be using getChildFragmentManager()?

Comment: add your xml files containing fragment, chances are you haven't put an id tag in or you have duplicate/not sufficiently allocated IDs

Comment: @sirFunkenstine already tried with getchildfragmentmanager..but stil same error

Comment: @Hughzi you can see my whole structure in given link..

Comment: @Hughzi see my updated question and eror

Comment: android:name="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FragmentDrawer"

Is this the package path to your activity or theirs?

Comment: i have package info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should replace this line

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

With this

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Because firstly you initializing non-support fragment manager to support fragment manager instance.
Secondly as you define you container_body  frame layout inside activity drawer layout then you must replace it using activity fragment manager.

Answer (score 1):

@Roman: For your information

### What was your mistake

Fragments were available from target **API shall >= 11**.
[getFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) is used for *API>=14*,
and [getSupportFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) will used in support lib such as `v4` which also support older API. So if you use AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity then you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead
`getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling another fragment from within a fragment, I recommend you to use a Interface and call the fragment from the activity. Fragment withing fragment can result in long lived references.